# Does UIImagePicker Controller has access to all functionalities in IOS 7/IOS 8 camera app?

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

My requirement is to create a camera application, which contains all the functionalists like Photo,Video,Slow mo,Pano, filters.(like below screen)

[image]

My idea is to call the native camera api. I tried `UIImagePickerController` with options like this
`cameraPickerUI.showsCameraControls =YES;` but i can't bring filters, pano, slow mo option inside my application.

UIImagePicker Controller has access to all functionalities of camera api?

Using `UIImagePickerController` how to implement slow mo, filters,pano?(tiny help/ direction is more appreciated)
Please share  your thoughts,suggestions,idea.

My device is IOS 7 version only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it with `UIImagePickerController`. `UIImagePickerController`, it has not such kind of functionalities except crop facility.

You can use BradLarson's [**GPUImageView**](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/iOS/GPUImageView.h) framework, with that you can do what you want.